# angular typahead fetch results with starting letter only

Tags: angular-ui-typeahead

JS Code below :

$scope.startsWith = function(state, viewValue) {
                return state.substr(0, viewValue.length).toLowerCase() == viewValue.toLowerCase();
        }

> html< start tag< input name="states" id="states" type="text" placeholder="Search Countries..." ng-model="selected" typeahead="state.COUNTRY_CODE as state.COUNTRY_DESC for state in states | filter:$viewValue:statestartsWith | limitTo:8">

This is still not searching for first letter, it is giving results matching in middle of the string also. Please help

Answer (score 0):

The order of filters are incorrect.

```
typeahead="state.COUNTRY_CODE as state.COUNTRY_DESC for state in states | startsWith:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
```

In order to make it work, you have to define the function startsWith as a filter in your angular app. 
[See this angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Also your parameter name is state but the typeahead will return the country code of the state so be careful with your variable names.